# Audio map of the Globe

Tags: collaboration, ideas, map

So i was sitting at the beach the other day.  It was pretty much the first day of warm weather (summer) in San Francisco.  Anyways, I was thinking that all along the coastline of almost any place in the world is a bunch of wave sounds.  Then I thought about how one could map the world through sound.  Decidous forests would have a color, the artic etc...wind patterns, reflection patterns.
So has this been done?

Answer (score 5):

There's already a project in full swing by the BBC.

http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/specialreports/saveoursounds/index.shtml

Comment: Oh, neat!  I'm going to obscure Maine with all of my recordings :)

Comment: @ianjpalmer do you know what the CC/fair use license is on these sounds? This could be very handy the next time I need some Tanzanian ambience.

Comment: That is cool...

Answer (score 3):

yea the one on the bbc is nice. 
I also use http://aporee.org/maps/ and freesound.org, the last is a huge collection of creative commons samples but using the geotag function you can visualize just the field recordings and soundscapes.

Comment: I'm an avid contributor to Aporee Maps as well, 8000 sounds and growing. There is an app for mobile phones in development including gps tracking and listening.

Answer (score 2):

I've recorded the shore along northern Puget Sound and in Mt. St. Helens Volcanic National Monuement's forest.  Wouldn't be anything to grab around Mt Baker National Forest. So if it hasn't, I say we start.

Answer (score 2):

There is http://www.soundtransit.nl/ which allows you to "book" a sound journey. I've also come across many sound map projects.

Global: http://aporee.org/maps/

Prague: http://panto-graph.net/favouritesounds/

London: http://www.soundsurvey.org.uk/index.php/survey/soundmaps/

New York: http://www.nysoundmap.org/

Montreal: http://cessa.music.concordia.ca/soundmap/en/

Cologne: http://soundmap-cologne.de/

Taranto: http://sonorapuliae.altervista.org/soundmap.html

Madrid: http://www.madridsoundscape.org/

Basque country: http://www.soinumapa.net/

Galicia: http://www.escoitar.org/

Tokyo Yamanote Line Sound Map: http://www.rickbenedict.com/jams/?p=701

and probably a dozen more by the end of this week...

Answer (score 1):

I actually got sent this link today

http://soundbum.org/

which is along the lines of what you are suggesting - makes intesting listening too.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the ones previously mentioned, there are a few other projects that have been mentioned on the Phonography Users Group on Yahoo.  Definitely a cool idea.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to look into acoustic ecology, which people such as Murray Schafer and Barry Truax starting studying in the '60s. http://www.acousticecology.org looks like a good resource.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the new sound map I've developed, the best of course  on [www.ecnelisfly.com](https://www.ecnelisfly.com/mapfly_en)
The originality of this map is that you can choose between 250 categories.

Enjoy